# How to properly configure node.js to use Self Signed root certificates?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

So, on the road of desperation, I would want to know if someone, somewhere, can help me to configure nodejs to accept a root CA self signed. I need it in order to access a custom API in development via node-fetch with TLS.

## Envrionment

- OS : Ubuntu 20.04 as a guest in a VM. Windows 10 host.
- Nodejs v15.12.0
- Apache2.4 server

The API I'm working on is a PHP script that allow my nodejs backend to query some data.

The self signed root cert and API cert have been generated with openssl and are eprfectly fine, since I can query the API from the browser with HTTPS without any problem.

## The error

When trying to query the API from the nodejs backend, I get this error :

```
FetchError: request to https://myapi.dev.local failed, reason: self signed certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:462:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)"
```

## Tries & fails

First, I tried to install the cert on ubuntu with dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates, but then I figured that nodejs use a hard coded list.

So, since I do not want to use the `env` variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` for security sakes, I tried to use the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=pathToMycert.pem` en variable, but it doesn't change anything and I can't find any info to know what's going on.

In my nodejs backend, if I do a  `console.log(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS)`, it prints the good path.

I tried to match my CA against tls.rootCertificates whith this check :

```js
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const ca = await fs.readFileSync(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS, 'utf8');
console.log(ca); //successfully print the CA, so it exists.
const inList = tls.rootCertificates.some( cert =>{
    console.log('testing ca : \n',cert);
    return cert == ca;
});
console.log(`CA is ${ !inList ? 'not' : '' } in rootCertificates list...`);
```

It prints 'CA is not in rootCertificates list'. Not a surprise.

So, I tried to monkeypatch the tls secureContext to include my certificate :

```js
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const origCreateSecureContext = tls.createSecureContext;

tls.createSecureContext = options => {
    const context = origCreateSecureContext(options);

    const list = (process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS || '').split(',');
    list.forEach(extraCert => {
        const pem = fs.readFileSync(extraCert, { encoding : 'utf8' }).replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        const certs = pem.match(/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n[\s\S]+?\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----/g);
        if(!certs) throw new Error(
            `SelfSignedCertSupport : Invalid extra certificate ${extraCert}`
        );
        certs.forEach(cert => context.context.addCACert(cert.trim()));
    });

    return context;
};
```

Doesn't work.

And I tried (following this issue : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27079) to do this :

```js
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const additionalCerts = [];
const list = (process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS || '').split(',');
list.forEach(extraCert => {
    const pem = fs.readFileSync(extraCert, { encoding : 'utf8' }).replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    const certs = pem.match(/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n[\s\S]+?\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----/g);
    if(!certs) throw new Error(
        `SelfSignedCertSupport : Invalid extra certificate ${extraCert}`
    );
    additionalCerts.push(...certs);
});

tls.rootCertificates = [
    ...tls.rootCertificates,
    ...additionalCerts
];
```

Without any luck.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: (0) You're right the system (ca-certificates) store is irrelevant (1) I don't do odd majors and my Ubuntu 20.04 (with standard repos) can only find 10.19, but testing with 14.15.5 on Windows `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` works for me, assuming the file is good, which it should be if created by OpenSSL and not modified. Can you check `openssl x509 -in file` displays the cert with no error? (2) `tls.rootCertificates` gives you a copy of the builtin list only, not the actual X509_STORE that contains the adds, and patching it has no useful effect at all. ...

Comment: ... (3) Reading source I think `addCACert` also _should_ work, although you don't need the match+forEach (despite the singular name it actually accepts a sequence, but silently ignores invalid input) and you don't need to remove CRs (or 'comment' info)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. `openssl x509 -in file` printed the cert without error. I regenerated all my certificates and tried again. Still not working. 2 -> that's what I suspected... 3 : I tried to add the cert without mathing/changing the file content : not working. I also tried to add the CA at fetch level with the `ca` param : always the same error. I'll try the last version of node to see if it's a bug of the v15.12.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what's going on. This was a conjunction of two problems.

First, I generated my CA certificate and my other self signed certificates **with the same CN**. It's ok for all browsers and webservers, but not for node. For node, ensure that all your CN have **different names** (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23715832/5655434)).

The second problem is that the env var `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` is not working for somewhat reason in my environment. Trying to monkey patch as I tried works but is ugly, since `addCACert` is not a part of the public nodejs API. It should not be used. ​

Since I use the `fetch` API that depends on the `https` package, I created a little module that I require at the top of my backend nodejs app :

```js
if(!process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS) return;

const https = require('https');
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const list = (process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS || '').split(',');
const additionalCerts = list.map(extraCert => fs.readFileSync(extraCert, 'utf8'));

https.globalAgent.options.ca = [
    ...tls.rootCertificates,
    ...additionalCerts
];
```

This way, all requests that use `https` and does not redefine the `ca` options will read the ca list from the `globalAgent` and you don't have to pollute your codebase with ca specific code. In my case, I didn't want my dev environment to produce code that I'll have to remove in production.

So, now it works for me, even if I don't know what goiging on with the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` env var that doesn't do its job.

Comment: do you change NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS before startup? Docs say:

> The NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable is only read when the Node.js process is first launched. Changing the value at runtime using process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS has no effect on the current process.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file

Comment: @mmmm I was altering NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS in my bash environment through the commandline. But I suspect something altered the environment variable in my bash environment before node call, since I'm still unable to reproduce the issue with the same version of node in a similar environment.

Comment: OK, good luck to you. Sorry I cannot be of help with this