# setting NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS with dotenv does not work as an export

Tags: ssl, environment-variables, dotenv

I feel puzzled by the following behavior. In the very beginning of my main `index.js`, I am using

```js
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env);  // everything seems in order
```

I know that the rest of my code successfully access all the relevant `process.env.${VARS}`. However, I get SSL exceptions; exceptions that I can easily solve by

```sh
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/some/absolute/path/to/ca.pem
npm start
```

Is there something special about `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` that would explained why this specific variable set with `require('dotenv').config()` does not work while the others work like a charm?

Does it need to be set before running `npm`? If it does, why is it the case and are there any workaround so I could keep thing simple?

**environement**:

- dotenv 16.0.0
- node v16.13.2

Answer (score 2):

neardupe [How to properly configure node.js to use Self Signed root certificates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896243/how-to-properly-configure-node-js-to-use-self-signed-root-certificates) .

Your problem is not in `npm`. `npm start` runs *your application*, typically (but not necessarily) by running `node` (or whatever spelling on your platform) to run your js code. When you use `node` to run js, NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS is read and saved in the C-code part of `node` at startup, before beginning to execute js, and subsequent changes in js variables like `process.env` do not affect it.

The clean way to do this in js is to pass the desired CAlist -- which can consist of the standard list (from `tls.rootCertificates`) plus any additions (or replacements or deletions) you choose -- in the (relevant) TLS socket creation, or any https request that implicitly creates a TLS socket; or alternatively to use [--use-openssl-ca](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--use-bundled-ca---use-openssl-ca) and select an OpenSSL-format store provided by your system (modified if necessary by system means like `update-ca-certificates` on Debian/Ubuntu) or one you create.

Or when using npm as you do, it should be possible to configure your package.json to set the envvar before running the application in node.

If you can't do either/any of those, especially where you control the toplevel (and startup) but call libraries you can't [safely] change, see the Q I linked above. For `https` connections that use the default `https.globalAgent` you can (documentedly) set that per the A. For all connections, you can monkeypatch `tls.createSecureContext` to use the undocumented `context.addCACert` as in the Q, which OP confirmed in the A does actually work if using a correct cert.