# node TLS error on self signed certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, certificate, tls1.2

I'm trying to make client server communication using tls, but I got this error after running my client:

```sh
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)
Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
}
```

I found my code here : https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/253

this is my server.js file

```js
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 8000;

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.crt'), // authority chain for the clients
    requestCert: true, // ask for a client cert
    rejectUnauthorized: false, // act on unauthorized clients at the app level
};

var server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  socket.write('welcome!\n');
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.pipe(socket);
}).on('connection', function(c)
{
    console.log('insecure connection');
}).on('secureConnection', function (c)
{
    console.log('secure connection; client authorized: ', c.authorized);
}).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port + '\n');
});
```

then I start my server

this is my client.js

```js
const port = 8000;
const hostname = 'localhost';

const tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  host: hostname,
  port: port,
  // Necessary only if using the client certificate authentication
  key: fs.readFileSync('client.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client.crt'),
  // Necessary only if the server uses the self-signed certificate
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.crt')
};


var socket = tls.connect(options, () => {
  console.log('client connected', socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
  socket.end();
}).setEncoding('utf8')
.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).on('end', () => {
  console.log("End connection");
});
```

command I run for CA:

```sh
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

command I run for server:

```sh
openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt
```

command I run for client:

```sh
openssl genrsa -out client.key 1024
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt
```

Comment: Similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601989/client-certificate-validation-on-server-side-depth-zero-self-signed-cert-error