# DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error - How to generate the correct crt key

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I know this question has already been asked in one shape or form but I am still not able to get this to work after days of googling.

I am trying to open a TLS connection to an external API, say `example.com:8000`

I do not have any control over the external API, and I have provided them a `CRT` as they requested.

I have tried to generate the key in many different ways, but here is the latest:

Following:

[Client certificate validation on server side, DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601989/client-certificate-validation-on-server-side-depth-zero-self-signed-cert-error)

Generate ca using Common Name `Foo`

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -sha256  -new -nodes -key ca.key -days 999 -out ca.pem
```

Generate client key using Common Name `Bar`

```
openssl genrsa  -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -key client.key  -out client.csr
```

Generate requested CRT

```
openssl  x509  -req -days 999 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -in client.csr  -CA ca.pem  -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01  -out client.crt
```

I am testing with node using the following code:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

const port = 8000;
const hostname = "example.com";

const tls = require("tls");
var fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  host: hostname,
  port: port,

  key: fs.readFileSync("client.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("client.crt"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("ca.pem"),
};

var socket = tls
  .connect(options, () => {
    console.log(socket);
    process.stdin.pipe(socket);
    process.stdin.resume();

    socket.end();
  })

  .setEncoding("utf8")

  .on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })

  .on("error", console.log)

  .on("end", () => {
    console.log("End connection");
  });
```

Errors:

`ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC` when setting `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";`

or

`DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` without

Comment: *" I have provided them a CRT as they requested."* - what exactly did they request? Do they accept certificates signed by  some random non-public CA (like you create), do they expect a certificate issued by a specific CA or by an arbitrary publicly trusted CA or what exactly?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich they later shared this article with me https://devopscube.com/create-self-signed-certificates-openssl/ which now makes me think they want a self signed cert ?

Comment: Maybe? I would expect a more clear communication of what they want from you.

Comment: Your node application is acting as a TLS client, so I'm not sure what those error messages mean in that context. Is `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` the result of the node client rejecting its own certificate or is it rejecting its peer's (the server's)?